# Shortening jQuery Code by Replacing Variable

Tags: jquery

I have a form with a bunch of dropdown options that I'm dressing up by allowing the option to be selected by clicking links and (in the future, images) instead of using the actual dropdown.  There are a lot of dropdowns and most all will repeat the same basic idea, and some will literally repeat just with different variables.  Here's the HTML for one of those.

```
<tr class="box1">
  <td>
    <select id="cimy_uef_7">
      <option value="Boy">Boy</option>
      <option value="Girl">Girl</option>
    </select>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Then the corresponding fancier links to click that will select the corresponding option in the dropdown.

```
<div id="genderBox1">
  <div class="gender"><a class="boy" href="">Boy</a></div>
  <div class="gender"><a class="girl" href="">Girl</a></div>
</div>
```

So, when you click the link "Boy" it will select the corresponding dropdown value "Boy"  There are going to be multiple Box#, so I can just repeat the jQuery each time with the new variables, but there's surely a shorter way.  Here's the jQuery that makes it work.

```
//Box1 Gender
  var Gender1 = $('select#cimy_uef_7');
  var Boy1 = $("#genderBox1 .gender a.boy");
  var Girl1 = $("#genderBox1 .gender a.girl");

//On Page Load - Check Gender Box 1 Selection and addClass to corresponding div a
  if ( $(Gender1).val() == "Boy" ) {
    $(Boy1).addClass("selected");
    } else {
    $(Boy1).removeClass("selected");
    }

  if ( $(Gender1).val() == "Girl" ) {
    $(Girl1).addClass("selected");
    } else {
    $(Girl1).removeClass("selected");
    }

  //On Click - Change Gender Box 1 select based on image click
  $(Boy1).click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).addClass("selected");
    $(Gender1).val("Boy");
    $(Girl1).removeClass("selected");
  });

  $(Girl1).click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).addClass("selected");
    $(Gender1).val("Girl");
    $(Boy1).removeClass("selected");
  });
```

My thought for shortening it was to just have a list of variables for each box and cycle through the numbers- 1,2,3,4 and have the jQuery grab the same # for each variable, but I can't figure out a way to do it.

Let me know if there's anything else I can provide to make the question better.  This is my best idea for shortening this code, as I'm still very much a beginner at jQuery, but I'm positive there are much better ideas out there, so feel free to recommend a better path if you see it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a generalized solution.

Construct your HTML as follows, ensuring that the text contained by the anchors ("Boy" / "Girl") exactly matches the values of the corresponding menu options.

HTML:

```
<tr class="box1">
  <td>
    <select class="remoteSelectable" id="cimy_uef_7">
      <option value="Boy">Boy</option>
      <option value="Girl">Girl</option>
    </select>
  </td>
</tr>

<div id="genderBox1" class="remoteSelector" data-menu="cimy_uef_7">
  <div class="gender"><a href="">Boy</a></div>
  <div class="gender"><a href="">Girl</a></div>
</div>
```

javascript:

```
//force select menus to same value as clicked remote link
$(".remoteSelector a").on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this).addClass('selected'),
        $container = $this.closest(".remoteSelector");
    $container.find("a").not(this).removeClass('selected');
    $('#' + $container.data('menu')).val($this.text());
});

//force remote links to reflect value of selected menu option
$(".remoteSelectable").on('change', function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $(".remoteSelector").filter(function() {
        return $(this).data('menu') == $this.attr('id');
    }).find("a").removeClass('selected').filter(function() {
        return $(this).text() == $this.val();
    }).addClass('selected');
}).trigger('change');
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/52Lr5/2/)**

Notes :

- The 'change' handler is triggered immediately to force the correct remote link to be styled 'selected'.
- The select menus may be hidden by moving them off-screen with absolute positioning, or with `display:none` if they are not part of a form that's going to be submitted.

If at any point (after the handlers are attached) the menus need to be changed programatically then do so as follows to ensure the corresponding remote link is kept up to date :

```
$("#cimy_uef_7").val('Girl').trigger('change');
```

Comment: This seems like it might be perfect.  I'll definitely be exploring this to see how it works for me! Thanks!

Comment: It works great!  It will work for every element I need without even needing to add variables to my script- everything is done in the HTML mark-up. Perfect solution!

Comment: Jerry, yup that's right. You can add further HTML without needing to add any more javascript. Providing every `<select class="remoteSelectable">` and its corresponding `<div class="remoteSelector">` is constructed as above, they will mutually update each other.

Comment: This is working great, but I have one more question: Is there any way to make it so that the text doesn't have to EXACTLY match the value, but simply contain it?  I've been playing with :contains but can't figure out a way to make it work.  I assume it has to go around here: `$('#' + $container.data('menu')).val($this.text());`

Comment: Yes, you could make the matching rule more liberal but that would introduce the possibility of making a wrong match in cases of similar text. A better approach is to stick with exact matching but independently of any displayed text. See this [updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/52Lr5/3/).

Answer (score 2):

First thing, once you instantiate a variable with the result of a jQuery call, you don't need to call the jQuery function again - for example:

```
var Girl1 = $("#genderBox1 .gender a.girl");
```

You don't need to call `$(Girl1)` anymore, you can just call it `Girl1`.

The jQuery call returns an array, which can be useful if there is more than one matching element, so:

```
var girls = $(".gender a.girl");
```

`girls` is now an array of `a` tags. I believe they are in the order of the DOM, so that might work for you. Try running it through the Chrome developer tools or Firebug or whatever, and you should be able to see the array.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on calling the variable and the array info!

Answer (score 2):

Hi a bunch of things to consider

1) It's a good practice to use lowerCamelCase in your variable's name in JS

2) I'd not do the div manually, but dinamically as follows:

```
var genderSelect = $('select#cimy_uef_7'),
    genderOptions = genderSelect.children(),
    genderStyled = $('<div class="gender-styled-container"></div>');

genderOptions.each(function(i, option) {
    var newOption = $('<a href="#" class="option">' + option.innerText + '</a>');
    newOption.bind('click', function(evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        genderStyled.children('.option').removeClass('selected');
        newOption.addClass('selected');
        genderSelect
            .find('option:selected')
                .removeAttr('selected')
                .end()
            .find(option).attr('selected', 'selected');
    });
    genderStyled.append(newOption);
});
genderSelect.hide().after(genderStyled);
```

3) Example implemented at http://jsfiddle.net/Uz6cV/

Why? Because you want, on one hand, to behave still as a select box, and on the other hand, you want options in the new UI to depend on options in the select (you don't want the user to see an option that's not currently on the select, then cannot be submitted).

Remove the hide() on the last line to see the select and how it changes on clicking a new option.

Comment: That's a great idea that I'll definitely have to look into in order to find my final solution.  The only thing it's missing is that it doesn't check to see what option is already selected on page load and then select that option in the dynamically created html.  Also, how do I go about doing a second box, as there will be an identical ones on the same page, without repeating all the code with a new genderSelect variable?  That's the core of my question.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

You may try this

```
$(function(){
    // Set selected class on load
    var currentVal=$('select#cimy_uef_7').val();
    fl=(currentVal[0]).toLowerCase();
    currentVal=fl+currentVal.substr(1);
    $('#genderBox1 .gender a.'+currentVal).addClass('selected');

    // Click handler
    $('#genderBox1 .gender a').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parents('div#genderBox1').find('a').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');
        $('select#cimy_uef_7').val($(this).text());
    });
});​
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Q6bsr/2/).

**Update:** Also you may [try this](http://jsfiddle.net/Q6bsr/4/) for multiple selects or [even better](http://jsfiddle.net/Q6bsr/5/) using `data-` in divs.

Comment: Like some of the others, this one works and is certainly shorter than what I have, but in order to add a second box with identical options on the same page, I would have to repeat the jQuery and replace #genderBox1 with #genderBox2 and select#cimy_uef_7 with select#cimy_uef_###.  I updated [your demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Q6bsr/3/) with the example html. Thanks for your time, and I apologize if that wasn't clear enough in my question.

Comment: @Jerry, [you may try this](http://jsfiddle.net/Q6bsr/4/) but also notice the use of `prev` in this case, which means placement of elements are related.

Comment: @Jerry, [this is also better](http://jsfiddle.net/Q6bsr/5/), just see the `data-select` in divs.

Comment: I've never used data-select, but the most recent one that addition seems like it could very well be what solves my question.  I still have to try out all these other suggestions. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

well the following code block

```
//On Click - Change Gender Box 1 select based on image click
  $(Boy1).click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).addClass("selected");
    $(Gender1).val("Boy");
    $(Girl1).removeClass("selected");
  });

  $(Girl1).click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).addClass("selected");
    $(Gender1).val("Girl");
    $(Boy1).removeClass("selected");
  });
```

**can be replaced by**

```
$("#genderBox1 .gender a").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $("#genderBox1 .gender a").removeClass("selected");
    $(this).addClass("selected");
    Gender1.val($(this).html());
});
```

**[demo](http://jsbin.com/ahugum/1/edit)**

Comment: Class name's first character is upper case on select list, but lower case in anchor tag. this will not work.

Comment: who said it will not work, just check out the link given in answer,
and based on your point I have used `.html()` instead of `classname`

Comment: You're right- it works!  Thanks for helping shorten that chunk of code down.  Hopefully that will help the final answer of how to replace the variables even easier :)

Comment: And apparently I don't have enough reputation yet to upvote it.  Thank you for the help though!

Answer (score 0):

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/tariqulazam/aadDL/

I would modify the HTML like below. Please note the addition of gender class in the links. The whole idea behind the naming of classes and related elements is to reference them easily.

```
<tr class="box1">
  <td>
    <select id="cimy_uef_7">
      <option value="Boy">Boy</option>
      <option value="Girl">Girl</option>
    </select>
  </td>
</tr>


<div id="genderBox1">
  <div><a class="gender Boy" href="">Boy</a></div>
  <div><a class="gender Girl" href="">Girl</a></div>
</div>
```

​and here is the revised jquery code which will do the same thing

```
$(".gender").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $("#cimy_uef_7 option:contains("+ $(this).text() +")").attr('selected','selected');
});

$("#cimy_uef_7").change(function(){
    $(".gender").removeClass('selected');
    $("a." + $(this).val()).addClass('selected');
});
```